# How to Schedule Cron to Run Python script on varying intervals

Tags: python, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule a python script to run everyday for 1 week(7 days non stop) and then run once every week( 1 time in 1 week).

I have this in my crontab -e

```
48 10 * * ? * /path-to-python-file
```

This runs the script at 10:48 am everyday.

I want it to run it as per the the schedule explained before. 
How can I do that with cron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can create Local task schedule script on own computer.
On **Cpanel** server has **cron jobs** option. Here you can set command for particular urls and also **email** notify.

for eg.: /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/cron.php(filename)

[More details link description here](https://kb.iweb.com/hc/en-us/articles/230244168-Setting-up-cron-jobs-with-cPanel-)